# Find and replace only at the beginning of a line

Tags: mysql, regex, perl, replace, find

I am brand new to Perl (as in, just started playing with it out of necessity this afternoon) because I'm having to deal with some large, cumbersome text files that need to be turned in to .sql. After working through a couple of basic regex find/replace operations, I used the following line:

```
s/$/');/g;
```

And I ended up with 300k+ lines that look like this:

```
');INSERT INTO `test` VALUES('aa1b','MediaWiki1Deletecomment','1',5609');
```

Oops. So that was just supposed to put the `');` at the END of each line, but clearly I misunderstood and it stuck it at both the beginning AND end of the line. So a couple of questions:

1. How would I have done this correctly? Obviously I'm misunderstanding `s/$/');/g;`
2. How do I fix this file now that I've inserted a `');` at the beginning of each line, how do I selectively search through each line and remove the `');` at the beginning of the line and not the end?

This Perl/Regex noob thanks you!

Comment: Your pattern is correct for appending `');` to the end of each line, but the `/g` switch is unnecessary. You tagged this question with `[mysql]`, so is it safe to assume you are running on some Unix-like platform?

Comment: Yes, I am. I guess I misunderstood what function the /g actually served.

Comment: And to fix your file, you can run `s/^'\);//;` on each line.

Comment: How are you reading the text files? `open` followed by `while (<$fh>) { ... }` or something different? Are you changing the value of `$/`, Perl’s input record separator? How are you writing the output?

Comment: I've got a .pl file I wrote that opens and writes to a .txt file. Then I simply have a foe loop that iterates through each line of the text file and applies whatever regex I've got going. So, for example:
for ( @lines ) {
 s/$/');/g; 
print;
}

Then I'm running the .pl file via terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest command to remove those leading characters is to use `.` to match any character and a quantifier to repeat it three times at the beginning of each line with a one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^.{3}//' infile
```

Comment: Well that certainly worked. Not 100% sure on why, but you've fixed my problem and given me something to research. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perl has an in–place editing facility enabled with the `-i` switch. Use it in your case as in

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe "s/$/');/" *.sql
```

This will create a bunch of `*.sql.bak` backup files with your original code, and the modified contents will be in your `*.sql` files.

To correct the already–hosed ones, run

```
$ perl -i.bak -pe "s/^');//" *.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for this Greg, I will definitely use this method in the future.